# android TabLayout and ViewPager does not work in Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, android-tablayout

First of all, I searched a lot, but the solutions are not worked, so I am here for help. the design lib used is 23.1.1

//MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

// main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    class = "com.tablayoutfragmenttest.FragmentTest"
    android:id="@+id/hahah"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

// Fragment

```
public class FragmentTest extends Fragment {

private TabLayout mTablayout;
private ViewPager mVp;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    mTablayout = (TabLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.bizfrag_tabs_id);
    mTablayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
    mVp = (ViewPager)v.findViewById(R.id.bizfrag_vp_id);
    mVp.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
    mVp.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
    //mTablayout.setupWithViewPager(mVp);
    //mTablayout.post(new Runnable() {
    //        @Override
    //        public void run() {
    //                if (ViewCompat.isLaidOut(mTablayout)) {
    //                    mTablayout.setupWithViewPager(mVp);
    //                } else {
    //                    mTablayout.addOnLayoutChangeListener(
    //                         new  View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    //                            @Override
    //                            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
    //                            mTablayout.setupWithViewPager(mVp);
    //                            
    //                        mTablayout.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
    //                        }
    //                    });
    //                }
    //            }
    //        });


    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mTablayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mTablayout.setupWithViewPager(mVp);

        }
    });
}
}
```

//fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/bizfrag_tabs_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/bizfrag_vp_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

//ViewPager's adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public static String[] totalPossibleTabs = new String[]{"this is tab0", "this is tab1", "this is tab2", "this is tab3", "this is tab4", "this is tab5", "this is tab6", "this is tab7", "this is tab8", "this is tab9"};

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new Fragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return totalPossibleTabs.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return totalPossibleTabs[position];
    }
}
```

when I run the app, and swipe the page, the problem is as follows:
[the tab's indicator is in wrong position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp78L.png)

Comment: thanks for the note, I know the 0 is invalid as parameter. Actually, My question is about  using ViewPager and TabLayout together in an Fragment, anyway, thx

Comment: I use CoordinatorLayout in fragment.xml, but without lucky

Comment: I think the situation described in this question will be very common in usual development, didn't you guys come to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
if (ViewCompat.isLaidOut(tabLayout)) {
    mTablayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
} else {
    tabLayout.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(...) {
            mTablayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

            mTablayout.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
        }
    });
}
```

instead of:-

```
 mTablayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mTablayout.setupWithViewPager(mVp);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys, I finally find the point, 
we just cannot use

```
new Fragment();
```

in this case for simplicity, 
change it to your own Fragment.